# Error while trying to login to google via google OAuth API

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud

Error while trying to login to Google using OAuth from a website? appreciate any help or direction.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(Ljava/util/EnumSet;)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders.<init>(HttpHeaders.java:68) 
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.<init>(HttpRequest.java:69) 
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.buildRequest(HttpTransport.java:121)
```

Comment: You probably have an older version of the Google client library at runtime than the one it was compiled with.

Comment: Are you sure that the build using `ant clean all` passe with success ?